# Felica system codes and ISO 7816 identifiers for NFC on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, nfc, iso

I am making a mobile application in flutter and ran into a problem.

In my app, you need to be able to scan an NFC chip using the phone's scanner.
It works fine on Android, but when I try to build it for Apple, it says there's a problem with the properties in the Info.plist file.

It wants me to add some codes here. It needs Felica system codes and ISO 7816 select identifiers. Both of which I don't know.

```
<array>
    <!-- Add the Felica system codes here -->
    <string>System Code 1</string>
    <string>System Code 2</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <!-- Add the ISO 7816 select identifiers here -->
    <string>Select Identifier 1</string>
    <string>Select Identifier 2</string>
</array>
```

I tried searching online for these codes and what they represent, but I wasn't able to find anything. I also tried asking ChatGPT and it told me that Felica system codes are from the company FeliCa in Japan, but my nfc chips aren't from that company, so how do I get them?
And same thing about ISO 7816 identifiers.

Can someone explain what these codes and identifiers are and how I can get them?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Scan with android application, and you will see system code and manufacturer's code, something like 0x